# How to Create SeckeyRef from exponent and modulus of Public key and use in SecKeyEncrypt method

Tags: iphone, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

Anyone please help in Creating `SecKeyRef` from Exponent and Modulus being my `Public exponent` = **010001**
and `Public Modulus` =**008903fb6d15f352ed3b45add3216f632f7139954a5631337aba7d645ed38482e3a810b4db26aab4d1df58c147230f0c75631a3dd0554b50de44e79f4fcf205c89fd3f80e0ff8d16c2e9f56ed3ab177953d54c9c30357d04e677cedd9912906ef8a046d7b0185b7f2022a8e435b0c6ecaef93f089fc3aa3f3677550b5d842046c7** and i want to use this SecKeyEncrypt as public key

Comment: Purnima,
Could you paste the complete code. I see the code converting exponent & modulus to NSData but I didnt converting to SecRefKey (which is preference public key). Thanks in advance. -Kiran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem  `NSData *publicTag=[self PublicKeyItems];` in Generating keypair and calling the method
try importing BasicEncodingRules.h and .m in your file

```
- (NSData *)PublicKeyItems
{
NSString *exp = @"010001";
NSLog(@"Publickeyexp -%@",exp);
NSData *publickeyexpdata= [self stringasdata:exp];
NSLog(@"publickeyexpdata = %@",publickeyexpdata);
NSString *mod = @"008903fb6d15f352ed3b45add3216f632f7139954a5631337aba7d645ed38482e3a810b4db26aab4d1df58c147230f0c75631a3dd0554b50de44e79f4fcf205c89fd3f80e0ff8d16c2e9f56ed3ab177953d54c9c30357d04e677cedd9912906ef8a046d7b0185b7f2022a8e435b0c6ecaef93f089fc3aa3f3677550b5d842046c7";
NSLog(@"Publickeymod -%@",mod);
NSData *publickeymoddata= [self stringasdata:mod];
NSLog(@"publickeymod = %@",publickeyexpdata);

NSMutableArray *publicarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[publicarray addObject:publickeyexpdata];
[publicarray addObject:publickeymoddata];
NSData *testData = [publicarray berData];
NSLog(@"testdata = %@",testData);
NSMutableArray *testArray2 = [testData berDecode];
NSLog(@"testarray = %@",testArray2);
//STAssertEqualObjects(testArray, testArray2,
                    // @"Big items decode failed");

NSData *testData2 = [testArray2 berData];
 NSLog(@"PublicKeyData using Publickeyitems = %@",testData2);
return testData2;
}
-(NSData *)stringasdata:(NSString *)command {
command = [command stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
command = [command stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
command = [command stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"command= %@",command);
NSMutableData *commandToSend= [[NSMutableData alloc] init]; unsigned char whole_byte;
int len = [command length];
int n = len/2;
char byte_chars[3] = {'\0','\0','\0'}; int i;
for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
    byte_chars[0] = [command characterAtIndex:i*2]; byte_chars[1] = [command         characterAtIndex:i*2+1]; whole_byte = strtol(byte_chars, NULL, 16); [commandToSend appendBytes:&whole_byte length:1];
}
// [commandToSend setLength:[commandToSend length]-1];
return commandToSend; 

}
```

Comment: I'm hardly an objective-c wizard, but I haven't got a clue what you are doing in this piece of code. Could you explain?

Comment: I am trying to get the public key using exponent and modulus through the methods

Comment: I don't know if this matters, you may be should add the modulus and then the exponent to the array. Did it work for you?

Comment: how are you extracting modulus from SecKeyRef?

Comment: This code snippet doesn't do anything with SecKey like the original question mentioned. Can you update to include the entire process resulting in a valid SecKey instance?