# Implicit declaration of function STAssertEqualObjects is invalid in C99? why?

Tags: ios

i want to do encrypt an message in iphone. i have modulus and exponent.
the code i have do with reference from

[How to Create SeckeyRef from exponent and modulus of Public key and use in SecKeyEncrypt method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516355/how-to-create-seckeyref-from-exponent-and-modulus-of-public-key-and-use-in-secke)

```
+(NSString *)encryptRSA:(NSString *)plainTextString key:(NSString *)key
{

     NSString *publicKeyIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.publickey",[[NSBundle   mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
     [Crypto setPublicKey:key tag:(NSString *)publicKeyIdentifier];

     SecKeyRef publicKey = NULL;
     NSData * publicTag = [self PublicKeyItems/*publicKeyIdentifier      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding*/];
     NSMutableDictionary *queryPublicKey = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
     [queryPublicKey setObject:(id)kSecClassKey forKey:(id)kSecClass];
     [queryPublicKey setObject:publicTag forKey:(id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
     [queryPublicKey setObject:(id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(id)kSecAttrKeyType];
     [queryPublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(id)kSecReturnRef];

     SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey, (CFTypeRef *)&publicKey);

     if (!publicKey)
     {
         if(publicKey) CFRelease(publicKey);

         [Exception raise:FAILURE function:__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ line:__LINE__ description:@"Could not decrypt."];

}
```

i also use both BasicEncodingRules.m & .h. but i have a warning

```
+ (NSData*) PublicKeyItems

{

    NSString *exp = @"010001";
    NSLog(@"Publickeyexp -%@",exp);
    NSData *publickeyexpdata= [self stringasdata:exp];
    NSLog(@"publickeyexpdata = %@",publickeyexpdata);
    NSString *mod = @"008903fb6d15f352ed3b45add3216f632f7139954a5631337aba7d645ed38482e3a810b4db26aab4d1df58c147230f0c75631a3dd0554b50de44e79f4fcf205c89fd3f80e0ff8d16c2e9f56ed3ab177953d54c9c30357d04e677cedd9912906ef8a046d7b0185b7f2022a8e435b0c6ecaef93f089fc3aa3f3677550b5d842046c7";
    NSLog(@"Publickeymod -%@",mod);
    NSData *publickeymoddata= [self stringasdata:mod];
    NSLog(@"publickeymod = %@",publickeyexpdata);

    NSMutableArray *publicarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [publicarray addObject:publickeyexpdata];
    [publicarray addObject:publickeymoddata];
    NSData *testData = [publicarray berData];
    NSLog(@"testdata = %@",testData);
    NSMutableArray *testData1 = [testData berDecode];
    NSLog(@"testarray = %@",testData1);


    STAssertEqualObjects(testData, testData1, @"Big items decode failed");
// warning at this line, with content "Implicit declaration of function STAssertEqualObjects is invalid in C99"

    NSData *testData2 = [testData1 berData];
    NSLog(@"PublicKeyData using Publickeyitems = %@",testData2);
    return testData2;
}
```

so i can't build Crypto.o

please help me!
Thanks anyway

Comment: sorry everyone, i post code the first time so have alots of mistake

Answer (score 0):

STAssertEqualObjects is for use with SenTest (i.e., the unit test framework that comes with xcode).  Is this code in a Unit Test?  If not, then that's your problem.  Try `NSAssert*`.

Comment: this Crypto.m just a class to refer some function, not use for UI. tks for your reply

Comment: NSAssert/*STAssertEqualObjects*/(testData, testData1, @"Big items decode failed"); another warning

Comment: Sorry, but that does not mean much to me.  More information, please.